# Why is is my code not being read as having 0 be a valid response?

Tags: c++

I'm having an issue in the area of the code where I have the user press 0 to output a string or to output a numerical value of hours. It will only have the latter option execute and I'm not sure why.

---

```
//Do you want the minutes converted into hours?                
if ((a != 0) && (a != 1)) {
  cout << "That is not a valid answer. Please try again.";
}
  else if (a = 0) {                           <----- My issue with the code is here.
      cout << "Thank you for using the program";
  }
      else if (a = 1) {                       <----- My issue with the code
        average_hours_per_day = average_minutes_per_day/hour;
        cout << average_hours_per_day;
      }
```

---

Comment: You are assigning 0 to a in your line `else if (a = 0)`, which should be `else if (a == 0)`. Same for the `else if(a = 1)`, which should be `else if (a == 1)`

Comment: Thanks for helping. I'm still pretty new here, so I wasn't sure if I needed all my code or not.

Comment: @ShuhabAhmedMusic If you haven't checked out [ask], you should. That's a good reference for what is expected of a question.